# Limit amount of emails sent per time frame?

Tags: 7, emails

Is there a module which allows for the limiting of emails sent per hour using drupal mail system?

My server has a limit of how many emails can be sent per hour. Most of my users are online at the same time of the day, so it makes sense to spread the emails out over the day rather than sending all at once.

But the only mail modules I've found so far send all emails in one go rather than being able to limit the amount per hour.

How can I set Drupal to limit the amount of emails it sends per hour and all unsent emails are queued for the next hour?

Thanks

Comment: [Queue Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/queue_mail) most likely.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option, [Queue mail module](https://www.drupal.org/project/queue_mail) that queues all output emails in the queue ( you can define what email Ids queue). then set Cron to run each hour with [ultimate_cron module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron))

the only problem is that you can not define how many hours can be sent in a Cron run. you can just set how many seconds the Cron can be run ( Queue processing time) . I think with a couple of tries you find your desire time.

[image]